# PyPdf2 merge with scanned PDF yields "An error exists on this page..."

Tags: pypdf

I want to use PyPDF2 to take each page of a scanned PDF document,

- scale the page to 85% of its original size
- and center the page on a blank 8.5 by 11 page
- with the same number of pages

to create margins that are needed for printing/adding barcodes.

I've tried a few approaches with `mergeScaledTranslatedPage` but I keep ending up with an error message when I open the file in Adobe Acrobat DC.

Even if the output appears to be a success, I get the following error when opening the file:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.

How can I make it work?

Comment: did u solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of `pypdf` and `PyPDF2`. Please use `pypdf`.

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation
from pypdf.generic import RectangleObject

reader = PdfReader("GeoTopo.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()


desired_width = 100
desired_height = 100
r = RectangleObject([0, 0, desired_width, desired_height])

for page in reader.pages[:10]:
    old_width = page.mediabox.width
    old_height = page.mediabox.height

    a1 = desired_width / old_width
    a2 = desired_height / old_height
    factor = min(a1, a2)

    new_width = float(old_width * factor)
    new_height = float(old_height * factor)

    dx = (desired_width - new_width) / 2
    dy = (desired_height - new_height) / 2
    op = Transformation().translate(tx=dx, ty=dy)

    page.scale_to(width=new_width, height=new_height)
    page.add_transformation(op)
    page.mediabox = r
    page.artbox = r
    page.cropbox = r
    page.bleedbox = r
    page.trimbox = r
    writer.add_page(page)

with open("foo.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
``
```

Comment: Dear Martin I just tested this code. The changes reflect in pdf but cannot open the pdf file from Adobe Acrobar Reader. It says 'An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.'